# using client object model sharepoint to get date fields

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

Ok. this is not just a simple list. It is publishing pages library, each page is based on publishing page layouts and contain various fields like Start Date, End Date, Start Time, End time etc..(it is a publishing page for a school Event ). There is a jquery UI mini calendar on the page on which only those dates  that have events should be clickable. Now I need to get those dates values from the pages in the pages library. Lets say right now there 3 events in the pages library
(event1.aspx= this page will have its  'start date' field value, say Jan 20, 2012, 
event2.aspx=this page will have its  'start date' field value, say Jan 21, 2012, 
event3.aspx=this page will have its  'start date' field value, say Jan 22, 2012)

I need to grab those dates, 20, 21, and 22 using client object model. Can someone get me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example here
http://snahta.blogspot.com/2010/08/client-object-model-javascript-and-web.html

You can see how "Created" which is a date-time field, is accessed using Client Object Model

Another good article on COM 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094(office.14).aspx